# Arch Linux. Touchpad dosen't work sometimes on Huawei MateBook D15 Boh-WAQ9R

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad

I quite a long time from now use Arch Linux on my laptop Huawei MateBook D15 Boh-WAQ9R, and sometimes the touchpad just stops working. It may happen after sleep or after the start. So sometimes it works, sometimes not. I tried adding an 'i8042.reset' flag to boot parameters, but it not works. Right now my touchpad does not work and here some outputs.

```
$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ov9734_azurewave_camera: ov9734           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Huawei WMI hotkeys                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ libinput list-devices

...
Device:           ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             115x70mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
...
```

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices 

...
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=30f5 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2204:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2204:00/0018:04F3:30F5.0001/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 mouse1 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
...
```

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep "input driver"

[     3.824] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[     3.900] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[     4.020] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[     4.100] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.101] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.103] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[     4.192] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.194] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ov9734_azurewave_camera: ov9734'
[     4.372] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.373] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.374] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Mouse'
[     4.532] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.543] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ELAN2204:00 04F3:30F5 Touchpad'
[     4.790] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Huawei WMI hotkeys'
[     4.891] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     4.952] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 23213.669] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 23213.879] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 29009.006] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 29009.167] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 42170.849] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 42170.957] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 49296.716] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 49296.880] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 49345.002] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 49345.153] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 49400.260] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 49400.375] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 62336.190] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 62336.388] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
[ 68874.988] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 68875.141] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'PixArt HP X500 USB Optical Mouse'
```

Can someone help, or, at the list, direct to the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, for now my solution is to run

```
$ synclient TapButton1=1
$ synclient TapButton2=3
$ synclient TapButton3=2
```

in order to emulate

- one tap for click
- two tap for right click
- three tap for the middle click

You can also add this commans to the startup process to have a permanent effetct.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/382110/how-can-i-permanently-change-touchpad-settings

Comment: Thank you, i try this next time I will have this problem, but it looks like work around.